# getElementsByClassName showing null when there is an object with that class

Tags: javascript, html, shopping-cart

Trying to get a shopping cart on my website work, fails completely. For some reason, the getElementsByClassName method keeps returning null even though I can clearly see that one of the objects have that class eg. if there is an object with class "price" and I set a variable to that object using getElementsByClassName, it returns undefined for some reason.
Here is the js:

```js
var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
console.log(removeCartItemButtons)

for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
  var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
  button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
  })
}

function updateCartTotal() {
  var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
  var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')

  for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    var cartRow = cartRows[i]
    var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
    var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-amt')[0]
    console.log(priceElement, quantityElement)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/ktane-utils.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="cartCode.js" async></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.0/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">"Home"</a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html">"Store"</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cart.html">"Cart"</a></li>
                    <li><a href="account.html">"Account"</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>  
            
    <div class="section">
        <div class="page page-bg-01">
            <div class="page-header">
            </div>
            <div class="page-content">
            
            <table style='width: 100%'>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
            <div class="cart-items">
            <div class="cart-row">
            <tr>
                <td><span class="cart-name">Iphone 14 Max Pro, £899.99 </span><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Remove</button></td>
                <td><input class="cart-amt" type="number" value="1"></td>
                <td><span class="cart-price">£899.99</span></td>
            </tr>
            </div>
            </div>
            </table><br>
            
            <table style='width: 50%'>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td>£919.99</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            
            <div class="footer">
                <center><p>Email: <u>t.margub2112@gmail.com</u></p></center>
                <center><p>Facebook: <u>Tawhidul Islam@tawhidulislam.islam.524</u></p></center>
                <center><img style='width: 10%' src="img/pictures/Extra/icon.png" /></center>
                <p style="text-align:left;">Copyright 2022 - Tawhid Productions</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to see where the error was coming from, and it looked like the  element didn't allow the getElementsByClassName method in. I don't know how to fix it, as I want to keep the table. I expected it to just give the code named "cart-price" and "cart-amt", but it gave "undefined" and yet another "undefined"

Comment: By the time you call `updateCartTotal` you have already removed the row. But also why do you have a `div` in the middle of a table?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` may require a match of the full className, not just one class. I prefer `document.querySelectorAll(".btn-danger")`.

Comment: @pilchard That isn't the problem as if I put the code above the table row but inside the row div, it works. However, I don't want the table removed. Also, where would you request the div that contains a specific row of my table be put? I want the div to contain that specific row so I don't see where else I could put it.

Comment: divs are not valid children of table elements.

Comment: @pilchard so what can I use as the parent of the table rows?

Comment: table rows are always children of either the [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) or `<thead>` or `<tbody>` they don't get nested in any other element

Comment: @pilchard so what can I do to get the getElementsByClassName actually return the value inside the table?

Comment: I solved it now, needed to use <tbody> and <tr> as the containers, not two <div>s